# Sour Almonds use

Tags: almonds

We have loads of Almonds which have developed a strange back taste(maybe rancid) they are eatable but the flavor has changed probably due to extended storage , so we decided to extract oil out of it but is it good to use such almonds for oil? What are some other uses of such almonds?

Answer (score 4):

If they truly are rancid, then you should just discard them.  Any use of the almonds or their oil will just impart a terrible taste into the dish in which they are used.

If they have gone *sour* (I am not sure how that would be possible), then something is very wrong, perhaps an unusual type of spoilage, and similarly you should just discard them for safety reasons.

Either way, unfortunately, I don't think you should use them.

Comment: I dont know what to call it , I  used sour in the sense of unpleasant flavour

Comment: Either way, why would you want to use almonds with an unpleasant flavor?

Comment: Because they are very expensive here and I have loads of them.

Comment: Sadly, it is a sunk cost.  You put at risk anything you put them into, increasing the loss.

Comment: @Ali More than putting at risk the things you make with them, there's really just no point: if the almond flavor would be noticeable, the rancid flavor is going to be just as obvious, so either you might as well not have used them, or it'll be ruined.

Comment: So much this. If they are indeed rancid (and that seems the most likely way for nuts to go bad), it is fats that become rancid. If you extract oil from them, the oil will be rancid.

Answer (score 1):

Throw them out! If they look funny or smell funny do not ingest them. I recently took a graduate level Mycology lab course where we learned about the dangers of the fungus Aspergillus producing extremely toxic metabolites called aflatoxins, especially in nuts. The metabolites can stick around through processing, so oil extraction won't "clean" the almonds if they have become rancid with this type of metabolite. Seriously, don't mess any old nut products. They can really make you sick.

Comment: so what about external use of the oil as a massaging oil?

Comment: @Ali This goes outside of the site scope. But in general, contact with poisons is not what you want to have, through stomach, skin or otherwise.

Comment: Yes. Aflatoxins can be absorbed through the skin. See abstract of study relating to this here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1473792